# Firefox Cannot Connect When Running Java Selenium WebDriver With GeckoDriver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to run my Selenium test script with Firefox. So far, it works fine with Chrome but Firefox says "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at [any uri]". I need this to work for a system in which I am not the admin. I tried this in my own system and it worked fine. I'm not sure why Chrome would work in the former system and Firefox wouldn't. Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
System.setProperty("driver.gecko.webdriver", "drivers\\geckodriver.exe");    
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("www.google.com");
```

I've tried various approaches with setting different options and configurations, but none have worked. Most of what I have found through Google has been from an exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms

My problem does not relate to this at all as I do not have any exceptions. Another thing to note is that when I use Firefox myself, it connects just fine. The problem only happens when I run my scripts. I have also checked the proxy settings and they are fine.

EDIT:

```
OS version: Windows 7 Enterprise
GeckoDriver version: 0.23.0
Firefox version: 62.2.2esr
Java version: 1.8.0_181
Selenium version: 3.14.0
Eclipse version: 4.8.0 (Photon)
```

Comment: can you update your question with firefox version, geckodriver, java version, OS etc..

Comment: Just updated it. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: try update firefox browser.

Comment: I updated Firefox to 62.2.2esr. Same issue.

Comment: This issue is caused by mismatch between versions of selenium and driver. Ex: if the driver is newer but selenium version older. Quite weird issue .. do this happens only on firefox?

Comment: Yep just Firefox. I'm also using Chrome and it works fine. As of now, I believe I have the latest version of Firefox and geckodriver.exe. Let me double check though.

Comment: So I even tried GeckoDriver 0.21.0 and it still has the same issue.

Comment: The issue is isolated to being in the virtual machine I'm using. Automating Chrome works fine in it and using Firefox manually works too. The only time I get this issue is when automating Firefox. I would think it has something to do with permissions but then Chrome works so I don't know.

Comment: So the issue is not with the versions. All versions are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I just made a new update
selenium-java version 3.141.59
firefox 64
geckodriver v0.23.0
and all things worked well for me

Comment: I am on a new system now and everything is working well. I was on Windows 7 previously and moved to Windows 10. I'm not sure if it was an issue with Windows 7 or some security on my end, but it works now.